# Deleted Bootcamp Partition and Mac boots into broken windows

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, partition, startup

**problem**

So i got windows 10 on my mac and realized that i barely had partitioned enough space on windows so i booted back into Sierra and messed with the partitioning so i decided to delete the bootcamp partition, now everytime i boot up my mac it boots into windows but it gives me an error page so i have to hold "option" everytime i boot up my macbook.

Would reinstalling windows with bootcamp again solve this?

Btw when i open disk utilities, the bootcamp partition isn't even there which is weirder

Comment: When you get into macOS go into Settings->Startup Disk and select your macOS partition.

Comment: "decided to delete the bootcamp partition" .. how did you do this? Correctly, using Boot Camp Assistant, or 'without a safety net'?

Comment: @Allan hey allen the weird thing is that the windows paritition doesnt evne show there it just boots into windows for some reason

Comment: @Tetsujin i deleted it by using disk utilities

Comment: That's because the "record" is still on the small boot partition that has the bootloader.

Comment: For future ref: BCA is the way to remove a BC partition, or 3rd party apps such as [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) or [WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/) can "juggle" BC partitions without upsetting the Apple-cart ;)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a model Mac that Apple has documented to officially support Windows 10. If not, then this answer may not apply.

After holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the icons appear, you can permanently select default operating system to boot from by holding down the <kbd>control</kbd> key before selecting label below the desired icon.

Next, you have not completely deleted Windows 10. The Windows 10 boot files do not reside in the partition you deleted. The files actually reside in the first partition of the internal drive. This partition contains the volume labeled `EFI`.

Step to remove Windows files from `EFI` volume:

1. Enter the following command in a Terminal application window. This will mount the `EFI` volume. This volume will appear as the device labeled `EFI` in the Finder application.

   ```
   diskutil  mount  disk0s1
   ```
2. Remove the folders labeled `Boot` and `Microsoft` from the mounted `EFI` volume. The image below shows the location of these folders.

   [image: xxx1]
3. Enter the following command in a Terminal application window. This will unmount the `EFI` volume.

   ```
   diskutil  unmount  disk0s1
   ```